# How to use TRUE and PASS values for the test cases in Robot Framework?

Tags: robotframework

I am new to Robot Framework so I need help with this I am trying to do "RUN KEYWORD IF" ,if I look in docs they give 
**Run Keyword If |  '${status}' == 'PASS'   | Some Action   arg**.

My doubt is with this PASS value . How to get this as every time I Try ,I get a none value for every Keyword statement. I am trying to do something this :

```
*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
${name}      theon

*** Test Cases ***
Verify
    ${x}=    Set Variable    function
    Run Keyword If    '${x}==PASS'    Log 'True'
    ...    ELSE    Log    'False'

*** Keywords ***
function
    ${return}=    Should Equal    ${name}    theon
    [Return]    ${return}
```

I get error that x is defined NONE then how I can validate in the condition that my keyword is success or True.

I would also like some help with whether I can use a self defined keyword in place of 'condition' to run some keyword.

**RUN KEYWORD IF|| Some self keyword here which return me pass or true|| Target Keyword**

Answer (score 0):

What does **Should Equal** do? 
Since it does not exist in RF there is **Should Be Equal** but this just passes or fails the test. 
Note all **Should...** behave like this.

Maybe you want the evaluate if **${name}** and **theon** are equal (the same) then use **evaluate** ...

```
${return}=    evaluate    '${name}'=='theon'
```

Evaluate will return True or False

Then this will work.

```
Run Keyword if    ${x}    Log    True
```

Comment: Can I do this :  || Run Keyword if   |  ${return} = evaluate  '${name}'=='theon'  |  Log     True || ??...   In documentation they give the syntax   (( Run Keyword If '${status}' == 'PASS'  Some Action arg)) I want to use this 'PASS' somehow to nest my custom keyword in the CONDITION.

Comment: Why do you want to nest a keyword in the condition?

Comment: As far as I know Nested Conditions do not work in robot framework.

Comment: But this will work of cause
`Run Keyword if    '${name}'=='theon'    Log    Name is theon`
My answer was meant to adapt your example.

Comment: But still I'm not 100% sure what your `PASS` is. 
`*** Settings ***

*** Variables ***
${name}           theon

*** Test Cases ***
Verify
    ${x}=    function
    Run Keyword If    ${x}    Log    True
    ...    ELSE    Log    False
    Run Keyword If    '${name}'=='theon'    Log    True
    ...    ELSE    Log    False

*** Keywords ***
function
    ${return}=    evaluate    '${name}'=='theon'
    [Return]    ${return}
`

Answer (score 0):

Instead of "status", you can provide the "conditions" directly and then take a specific action using the "self defined keyword"

An example below :

```
Run Keyword if  ${medicine_expiry_year} > 2000 and ${medicine_expiry_year} < 2016    Send Mail to Company   ${company_mail_id}
Run Keyword if  ${medicine_expiry_year} == 2016  Report Remaining Months to Store operator  ${month_of_expiry}  
Run Keyword if  ${medicine_expiry_year} > 2016   Log     "Keep the medicine"
```

Conditions in Above Example :

```
${medicine_expiry_year} > 2000 and ${medicine_expiry_year} < 2016  
${medicine_expiry_year} == 2016
${medicine_expiry_year} > 2016
```

Self defined keywords with parameters :

Sends a Mail to Company using keyword "send Main to Company" with the mail id provided in "${company_mail_id}"

```
 Send Mail to Company   ${company_mail_id}
```

Report the Remaining Months to Store operator using the keyword  "Report the Remaining Months to Store operator" expiry month provided using variable "${month_of_expiry}   "

```
Report Remaining Months to Store operator  ${month_of_expiry}
```

Just Log the message using the keyword

```
Log  "Keep the medicine"
```

Hope so this was helpful.